# Change add to cart template on product view

Tags: magento2, layout, addtocart

I am using a slightly modified Luma theme and want to differ the text on the Add to cart button for product pages only. For this I have created another `addtocart.phtml` called `addtocartmain.phtml` which I want to use as the template for add to cart block for product pages. I have then attempted to override the default template using the below code within `vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` to the body node.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <action method='setTemplate'>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocartmain.phtml</argument>
        </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

The addtocartmain.phtml is located within:

```
'vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view'
```

After hours or attempting multiple methods of changing the template this is not changing the add to cart button. What could be stopping this from working? I can change the referenceBlock to any other block name and override them just fine with my new template. I have even removed all modules, removed everything but this one modification and tried making these modifications within the core vendor files and still this block is not changing.

Comment: FYI the action tag has been deprecated, `<arguments>` should be used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After tinkering around for a while I noticed that there was another block that was using the addtocart.phtml in the core:

```
'product.info.addtocart.additional'
```

Overriding this block and the original 'product.info.addtocart' block was they key to switching out my add to cart button with a new button on all pages. Add the below code to catalog_product_view.xml within the body node as suggested by thaddeusmt and Ben Crook.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocartmain.phtml" />
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocartmain.phtml" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to specify which module or theme directory the template is in. For instance, if it's in the `MyCompany_mytheme` theme, in the `Magento_Catalog` template override directory:

```
app/design/frontend/MyCompany/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocartmain.phtml
```

Try adding `Magento_Catalog::` to the path in `catalog_product_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocartmain.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

As Ben Crook noted in a comment though, `<action>` is being deprecated, so this is the correct way to do it now:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocartmain.phtml" />
```

That's assuming you are overriding the `catalog_product_view.xml` layout file correctly, of course. It should be here in your theme (if you are using a theme, not a module):

```
app/design/frontend/MyCompany/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

Be sure to clean the layout cache to check if it's working:

```
$ bin/magento cache:clean layout
```

Comment: Yeah i have it in correct place within theme and other modifications are working. I have tried adding Magento_Catalog however with no success.

Comment: I added one more suggestion: try using the "product.info.addtocart" block's `addtocart` alias in the `<referenceBlock>`

Comment: That is not working either

Comment: I just removed the suggestion about the `addtocart` alias, it didn't work. I also added the complete `catalog_product_view.xml` file. But I just tested the code above, and it works. Be sure to check the full path location of the `catalog_product_view.xml` file and `addtocartmain.phtml`. And remember, if this is a module, not a theme, the path will be different. Is this a module or a theme?

Comment: This is just in a theme. Path to layout is exactly as you have described and so is the template. catalog_product_view.xml is also exactly like yours other than a few extra rules.

Comment: Using your exact layout now in that location. Still nothing. This is gonna be a stupid mistake on my side somewhere.

Comment: I can use the code to override other blocks fine its just not liking that product.info.addtocart block at all so its not the location of phtml or layout or the code just that block.